# Magento2 How to add a "Dynamic Rows" in to the Product Insert area

Tags: magento2, products

I want to add dynamic rows with a dropdown field.how to add into the catalog product insert area thanks in a advance.

[image]

Comment: what you want ? your question is not clear. from where you want to add these rows? and where you want to show them ? give complete information.

Comment: Hello@HassanAliShahzad

I want this fields into the backend catalog -> product new section

Comment: You mean you want one drop-down in  Admin section. Can you let me know the Label and values you want to add for this section?
Also Is this field required ?

Comment: Hurry up man .....

Comment: Please see question,.i want this dynamic rows component

Comment: Possibly Duplicate https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205990/magento2-how-to-add-row-pattern-dynamic-rows-to-the-custom-product-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ui_component admin form take a dynamic rows container.Please refer the following code:

```
<container name="dynamic_rows_container">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
          <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/dynamic-rows/templates/default</item>
          <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dynamic Rows</item>
          <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">record</item>
          <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add Row</item>
          <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
      </argument>

      <container name="record">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dynamic Rows</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
            <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
          </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="row_id">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
              <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">row_id</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_label">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option Label</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_label</item>
              <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
              </item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_value">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option Value</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_value</item>
              <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cirklestudio_color_picker" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
              </item>
              <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
              </item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_price">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Option Price</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item><item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_price</item>
              <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
              </item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">30</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_class_id">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SVG Element Id</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_class_id</item>
              <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
              </item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="logo">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customproduct</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Zarathemes_Customproduct/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customproduct/index/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

      <!--<field name="option_img">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
              <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">file</item>
              <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">option_img</item>
              <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              </item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
            </item>
          </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="option_img_del">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delete image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">option_img_del</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> -->

           <actionDelete>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>

                       <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>

                       <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>

                       <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>

                       <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>

                       <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>

                   </item>

               </argument>

           </actionDelete>

           <field name="position">

               <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

                       <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>

                       <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>

                       <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>

                       <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Position</item>

                       <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">position</item>

                       <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>

                   </item>

               </argument>

           </field>

       </container>

   </container>
```

Comment: How to add label with dynamicRows as field (not as fieldset)? Do you know about that? In your ss, Hightlight Rows label display. I want to add that.

Comment: @Harhik, how can we limit to 5 rows maximum

Answer (score 2):

Here is how dynamic rows can be added by DataProvider.

Add DataProvider class as:

**etc\adminhtml\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customTab" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\NewField</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

And add DataProvider at:

**Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier:**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
class NewField extends AbstractModifier
{
const FIELD_IS_DELETE = 'is_delete';
const FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME = 'sort_order';
const FIELD_NAME_SELECT = 'select_field';

private $locator;
public function __construct(
    LocatorInterface $locator
) {
    $this->locator = $locator;
}
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    return $data;
}
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
     $meta = array_replace_recursive(
        $meta,
        [
            'custom_fieldset' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Custom Group'),
                            'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'data.product.custom_fieldset',
                            'collapsible' => true,
                            'sortOrder' => 5,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children' => [
    "custom_field" => $this->getSelectTypeGridConfig(10)
],
            ]
        ]
    );
    return $meta;
}
protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder) {
return [
    'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
                'addButtonLabel' => __('Add Value'),
                'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows',
                'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                'deleteProperty' => static::FIELD_IS_DELETE,
                'deleteValue' => '1',
                'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'children' => [
        'record' => [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                        'positionProvider' => static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME,
                        'isTemplate' => true,
                        'is_collection' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT => $this->getSelectFieldConfig(1),
                static::FIELD_IS_DELETE => $this->getIsDeleteFieldConfig(3)
                //Add as many fields as you want

            ]
        ]
    ]
];
}
protected function getSelectFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Options Select'),
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                    'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/custom-options-type',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                    // 'selectType' => 'optgroup',
                    'dataScope' => static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT,
                    'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    'options' => $this->_getOptions(),
                    'visible' => true,
                    'disabled' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
protected function _getOptions()
{
    $options = [
        1 => [
            'label' => __('Option 1'),
            'value' => 1
        ],
        2 => [
            'label' => __('Option 2'),
            'value' => 2
        ],
        3 => [
            'label' => __('Option 3'),
            'value' => 3
        ],
    ];

    return $options;
}
protected function getIsDeleteFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
    return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'componentType' => ActionDelete::NAME,
                    'fit' => true,
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: it's showing the required icon https://prnt.sc/15l3jyz