# Show thumbnail image via Data Provider in Dynamic Rows in admin form magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, adminform, file-upload, dynamic-rows, data-provider

How can I show image thumbnail (edit form) for dynamic rows created by Magento's Row Pattern using Data Provider / Modifier. Like this link:

[Magento2 How to add row pattern/dynamic rows to the custom product attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205990/magento2-how-to-add-row-pattern-dynamic-rows-to-the-custom-product-attribute)

My data saved in database as json format like below:
[{"record_id":"0","repairby":"1","note":"good","start_date":"","est_date":"","callback_date":"","hours_worked":"4","image":["Screenshot from 2021-05-17 15-58-43.png","Screenshot from 2021-05-20 13-08-23.png"],"initialize":"true"}]

[image]