# How to create row pattern/dynamic rows to the custom category attribute Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, dynamic-rows

How can we create a Dynamic Row/Row Pattern Attribute on the Category page?

[image]

Comment: Please take reference to this solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205990/magento2-how-to-add-row-pattern-dynamic-rows-to-the-custom-product-attribute. In this tutorial, there is a product attribute created. You need to create the category attribute for this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am taking reference to that question and I have done to save data on the table but as know that is for the product page, so I have an issue while rendering data on the category page. Do you know how to set data on that sections?

Answer (score 1):

```
<fieldset name="test">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Test</label>
        <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="answers">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answers</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">35</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <dynamicRows name="attribute_options_select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                    <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Answer</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="admin__field-wide" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>

                </item>
            </argument>
            <container name="record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isDelete" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="positionProvider" xsi:type="string">attribute_options.position</item>

                    </item>
                </argument>

                <field name="faq_answer">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answers</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faqs</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">25</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">faq_answer</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>

                <field name="ta">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="admin__field-small" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="readonly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rating</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faqs</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">tags</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="by">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="admin__field-small" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="readonly" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">By</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faqs</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">33</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">by</item>
                            <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="st">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faqs</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">st</item>
                            <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                            <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                                <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="position">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">position</item>
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input</item>
                            <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">option.order</item>
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>

                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```